# How do we combine the outer complexity of a recursive algorithm with the complexity of each call?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

This is my first time venturing in finding out the theoretical complexity of my algorithm. I started with [this useful link](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1176/handouts/midterm/5-BigO.pdf) for beginners shared around a few answers on this site to grasp the complexity of a recursive algorithm, but I need some extra insight.

In my case, additional steps take place inside the recursively called function `F(constants P, 2D matrix N)`:

```
function F:
  For i = 1:N
     If i satisfies condition
       Save information to a global variable
       Continue to i+1
     If i does not satisfy condition
       M = slicing of matrix N
       Call F(constants P, matrix M)
     End if
  End for
End function
```

I think for a recursivity depth of `k`, the big-O of the recursive algorithm is `O(k^n)`. Furthermore, I think each call of the function is `O(n)`. The worst case might be that the slicing barely removes any elements of the matrices, so that `N` and `M` are similar in size throughout the algorithm.

In MATLAB, the slicing of 2D matrices is done using logical indexing, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html#FindArrayElementsThatMeetAConditionExample-2). For example:

```
M = N(condition1 && condition2,:);
M = N(N(:,1) > 10 && N(:,3) - N(:,4) > 20,:);
```

How do you combine both concepts into a single expression?

Comment: Can you add some definitions here? Is i iterating the matrix line by line or element by element? How is the slicing of M works?

Comment: I added an example and a link to the documentation at the end. However, since I am relying on MATLAB's built-in logical indexing rather than doing the slicing with loops myself, I don't know if this information is good enough for the question.

Comment: If ever `N==M` you will have infinite recursion.

Comment: I now rephrased that sentence.

Comment: To answer the question we have to know how the slicing works. See @trincot comment if N=M. If N is always a bigger matrix than M, than the algorithm is no more than O(n^4), but this really depends on what is the iteration loop and how the slicing is done

Comment: Shouldn't the maximum recursion depth appear in the notation? Could you explain why it is to the 4?